# Cant import product image in magento 1.9

Tags: image, import, magento-1.9

When I importing product images getting an error like `Invalid image file type` i am using .png and .jpg(`/2811292016_05_26_12_10_13pm.jpg`). Please help me to solve this issue

[CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFdPX.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you show us some actual code that you used?

Comment: I attached my csv file above

Comment: help me to solve this issue